# How can I have my PHP script validate what was entered on my HTML form so that it will only display what was entered on that form?

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

First off, let me say that I am brand new to Databases and PHP. I have an html form that I am trying to use to filter through my php results. I can't for the life of me figure out how to set this up so that the form can filter every possible input, let alone without having any duplicate entries. I think the difficulty that comes in to play here is the fact that there is so much criteria to filter through. My form contains, checkboxes, drop downs to sort by, a text field that just needs to search through the title column, and another set of text fields to search between a specific date range. I'm losing it trying to figure this out. Please help me out.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Anime Database Search</title>
  <link href="vignette.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="body.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="banner">
    <p class="vignette"><img id="banner" src="Banners/SAO Banner.jpg" alt="Sword Art Online Banner" height="200px" width="100%"/></p>
  </div> <!-- end banner -->

  <div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <hgroup>
       <h2>Anime Database Search</h2>
    </hgroup>
  </header>

  <form id="search" action="database.php" method="GET">

  <b>Title:</b>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="search_box" value="" />

  <br>
  <br>

  <b>Release Date:</b>
    <br>
  <input type="us-date1" name="mindate"> to <input type="us-date2" name="maxdate">

  <br>
  <br>

  <b>Licensing Type:</b>
  <br>
    <select name="license">
      <option selected value="title">Licensing</option>
      <option value="dubbed">Dubbed Titles Only</option>
      <option value="subbed">Subbed Titles Only</option>
    </select> <!-- end license -->

  <br>
  <br>

    <b>Genres:</b> <div id="genres">
        <div id="left">
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Action</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Adventure</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Comedy</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Drama</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Fantasy</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Horror</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Magic</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Mecha</input><br>
        </div> <!-- end left -->
        <div id="right">
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Mystery</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Psychological</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Romance</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Science Fiction</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Slice of Life</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Supernatural</input><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action">Thriller</input><br>
        </div> <!-- end right -->
    </div> <!-- end genres -->

  <br>
  <br>

    <div id="Sort_By">
    <b>Sort By:</b>
    <br>
    <select name="Sort" required>
      <option value="">Select One</option>
      <option selected value="rating">Rating</option>
      <option value="alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
      <option value="released">Release Date</option>
    </select> <!-- end Sort -->
    </div> <!-- end Sort_by -->

  <br>

    <div id="search_buttons">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </div> <!-- end search_button -->

  </form> <!-- end search -->
  </div> <!-- end wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

// Include DB Connection File
include "connection.php";
?>

<!-- Stylesheet for Table -->
<style>
  <?php
    include "php_results.css"
  ?>
</style>

<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM my_anime_combined";

$fetch = mysql_query($query) or die($dberror1);
?>

<head>
  <title>Results</title>
</head>
<button onclick="history.go(-1);">Return To Search </button>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" border="1">

  <tr>
    <td id="results"><strong>Title</strong></td>
    <td id="results"><strong>Genre</strong></td>
    <td id="results"><strong>Season</strong></td>
    <td id="results"><strong>Episodes</strong></td>
    <td id="results"><strong>Released</strong></td>
    <td id="results"><strong>Media Type</strong></td>
    <td id="results"><strong>Sub/Dub</strong></td>
    <td id="results"><strong>Status</strong></td>
    <td id="results"><strong>Rating</strong><br><p>(5 stars)</p></td>
  </tr>
<?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)){ ?>
  <tr>
      <td id="title"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></td>
      <td id="genre"><?php echo nl2br($row['Genre']); ?></td>
      <td id="results"><?php echo $row['Season']; ?></td>
      <td id="results"><?php echo $row['Episodes']; ?></td>
      <td id="results"><?php echo $row['Released']; ?></td>
      <td id="results"><?php echo $row['Type']; ?></td>
      <td id="results"><?php echo $row['Licensing']; ?></td>
      <td id="results"><?php echo $row['Status']; ?></td>
      <td id="results"><?php echo $row['Rating']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  } //end $fetch
  ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your checkboxes are missing values, also their name should be an array.

Edit. This is only for guidence reasons, you shoudl sanitize every global after user input. Thx for reminder to wirite this @Brian Showalter

```
input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="action">Action</input><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="adventure">Adventure</input><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="comedy">Comedy</input><br />
```

In your place i would just do dynamic mysql query that would change depending on user pick and throw the data that he wants.

```
$stmt = 'Select * FROM my_table WHERE ';

if(count($_POST['action']) > 1){
         foreach($_POST['action'] as $action) {
             $stmt.= 'genre =' . $action . ' OR genre=';
          }

     $stmt = trim($stmt, ' OR genre=');

} elseif(count($_POST['action']) == 1) {
         foreach($_POST['action'] as $action){
             $stmt.= 'genre=' . $action;
         }
}else {
$stmt = trim($trim, ' WHERE ');
}
```

.edit: for example you could add above, it really depends how would you construct your SQL statement. Above would just make to select all records.

```
$stmt -- now you have here full statement will all action filters.
```

Next you can add title and license:

```
$stmt.=' AND title=' . ' $_POST['title'] . ' AND license =' .           $_POST['license'];`
```

You have to experiment to build a valid query, just var_dump or print_r a lot to see what you got.

Just glue the rest of your conditions into the $stmt and exec it. The rest is fairly simple to make.

Above code will loop through all genre fields and glue to your SQL QUERY you don't have to worry about that filed anymore.

By glue i mean add rest of conditions to your $stmt.

Here is the basic example how to do date based selects:

```
SELECT * FROM `la_schedule` WHERE `start_date` > '2012-11-18';
```

Comment: Plugging user input directly into a SQL statement like this is never a good idea. You really should read up on SQL injection and how it works.

Comment: Was only doing quick how to example, but you have right i should  mention that. Answer edited.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Just a couple more questions if you're able to answer. First is just to clarify what you mean by "glue the rest of your conditions," by that do you mean just repeat the process for each genre option and replace the names accordingly? Or something else I'm missing? The other question is about how I would then process the other options for it, like with the text fields for the title search, and the min-max dates? Same question for the licensing type drop down list.

Comment: @adam i have edited answer, now it should be more clear, if u still have some question, just post :]

Comment: Sorry if this question seems really idiotic, but with can you just elaborate what I would put between the Else {} statement instead of those dots "...."? I also updated my code to include "name='genre[ ]'" and added values to each genre with the title of that genre.